# Understanding the terms - Character Encodings, Fonts, Glyphs

Tags: unicode, encoding, fonts, internationalization, globalization

I am trying to understand this stuff so that I can effectively work on internationalizing a project at work. I have just started and very much like to know from your expertise whether I've understood these concepts correct. So far here is the dumbed down version(for my understanding) of what I've gathered from web:

Character Encodings -> Set of rules that tell the OS how to store characters. Eg., ISO8859-1,MSWIN1252,UTF-8,UCS-2,UTF-16. These rules are also called Code Pages/Character Sets which maps individual characters to numbers. Apparently unicode handles this a bit differently than others. ie., instead of a direct mapping from a number(code point) to a glyph, it maps the code point to an abstract "character" which might be represented by different glyphs.[ http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html ]

Fonts -> These are implementation of character encodings. They are files of different formats (True Type,Open Type,Post Script) that contain mapping for each character in an encoding to number.

Glyphs -> These are visual representation of characters stored in the font files.

And based on the above understanding I have the below questions,

1)For the OS to understand an encoding, should it be installed separately?. Or installing a font that supports an encoding would suffice?. Is it okay to use the analogy of a protocol say TCP used in a network to an encoding as it is just a set of rules. (which ofcourse begs the question, how does the OS understands these network protocols when I do not install them :-p)

2)Will a font always have the complete implementation of a code page or just part of it?. Is there a tool that I can use to see each character in a font(.TTF file?)[Windows font viewer shows how a style of the font looks like but doesn't give information regarding the list of characters in the font file]

3)Does a font file support multiple encodings?. Is there a way to know which encoding(s) a font supports?

I apologize for asking too many questions, but I had these in my mind for some time and I couldn't find any site that is simple enough for my understanding. Any help/links for understanding this stuff would be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what kind of project demands such an in-depth knowledge? Are you writing Operating System? Or a brand new GDI? For regular projects, you should know that you can convert just about anything to Unicode and use this as your default character encoding. Of course most of the fonts have only glyphs defined for some subset of Unicode categories, so knowing something about font fall-back won't hurt as well. Anyways, you probably should not reinvent the wheel, so I just wonder what you are up to...

Comment: Having said that, I must state that your question is not good fit for Stack Overflow, as it is not programming related (no code snippets would be involved). It is also unfortunately too broad, there is simply no way to give a short answer (one could write ***a book*** about this very topic). If you really want to go into that, you have huge mountain to climb. You'd have to master different writing systems, changes in character representation depending on the context, Ruby characters, kerning, hinting... and many more (in no particular order).

Comment: @Pawel Dyda: It is just an existing legacy java application at work that needs internationalization support. But I am just curious about this stuff. If it's too broad to cover, can you please provide links to articles/books so that I can learn it from there?. Moderators, Please move it to the appropriate forum.

Comment: The question is really a set of questions, and most of the questions are about concepts and fundamentals rather than technical questions about programming. The questions are important and interesting but better dealt with in books, articles, courses, and discussion forums. See e.g. the resources listed at http://www.unicode.org/resources/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn more, of course I can point you to some resources:

### Unicode, writing systems, etc.

The best source of information would probably be this book by [Jukka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084437/jukka-k-korpela):

[image]
[Unicode Explained](http://books.google.pl/books/about/Unicode_explained.html?id=PcWU2yxc8WkC&redir_esc=y)

If you were to follow the link, you'd also find these books:

[image]
[CJKV Information Processing](http://books.google.pl/books?id=htlttpi1KOoC) - deals with Chinese, Japanese, Korean and Vietnamese in detail but to me it seems quite hard to read.

[image]
[Fonts & Encodings](http://books.google.pl/books?id=qrElYgVLDwYC) - personally I haven't read this book, so I can't tell you if it is good or not. Seems to be on topic.

### Internationalization

If you want to learn about i18n, I can mention countless resources. But let's start with book that will save you great deal of time (you won't become i18n expert overnight, you know):

[image: Developing International Software]
[Developing International Software](http://books.google.pl/books?id=9bFQAAAAMAAJ) - it might be 8 years old but this is still worth every cent you're going to spend on it. Maybe the programming examples regard to Windows (C++ and .Net) but the i18n and L10n knowledge is really there. A colleague of mine said once that it saved him about 2 years of learning. As far as I can tell, he wasn't overstating.

You might be interested in some blogs or web sites on the topic:

- [Sorting it all out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/) - Michael Kaplan's blog, often on i18n support on Windows platform
- [Global by design](http://www.globalbydesign.com/) - [John Yunker](http://www.globalbydesign.com/blog/author/johnyunker/) is actively posting bits of i18n knowledge to this site
- [Internationalization (I18n), Localization (L10n), Standards, and Amusements](http://www.i18nguy.com/) - also known as i18nguy, the web site where you can find more links, tutorials and stuff.

### Java Internationalization

I am afraid that I am not aware of many up to date resources on that topic (that is publicly available ones). The only current resource I know is [Java Internationalization trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/). Unfortunately, it is fairly incomplete.

### JavaScript Internationalization

If you are developing web applications, you probably need also something related to i18n in js. Unfortunately, the support is rather poor but there are few libraries which help dealing with the problem. The most notable examples would be [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) and [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).
The prior is a bit heavy, although supports many aspects of i18n, the latter is lightweight but unfortunately many stuff is missing. If you choose to use Globalize, you might be interested in the latest Jukka's book:

[image: Going Global with JavaScript & Globalize.js]
[Going Global with JavaScript & Globalize.js](http://bytelevelbooks.com/books/global_javascript.html) - I read this and as far I can tell, it is great. It doesn't cover the topics you were originally asking for but it is still worth reading, even for hands-on examples of how to use Globalize.

Answer (score 2):

> Apparently unicode handles this a bit differently than others. ie.,
>   instead of a direct mapping from a number(code point) to a glyph, it
>   maps the code point to an abstract "character" which might be
>   represented by different glyphs.

In the [Unicode Character Encoding Model](http://unicode.org/reports/tr17/), there are 4 levels:

- **Abstract Character Repertoire** (ACR) — The set of characters to be encoded.
- **Coded Character Set** (CCS) — A one-to-one mapping from characters to integer **code points**.
- **Character Encoding Form** (CEF) — A mapping from code points to a sequence of fixed-width **code units**.
- **Character Encoding Scheme** (CES) — A mapping from code units to a serialized sequence of bytes.

For example, the character 𝄞 is represented by the code point U+1D11E in the Unicode CCS, the two code units `D834 DD1E` in the UTF-16 CEF, and the four bytes `34 D8 1E DD` in the UTF-16LE CES.

In most older encodings like US-ASCII, the CEF and CES are trivial: Each character is directly represented by a single byte representing its ASCII code.

> 1) For the OS to understand an encoding, should it be installed
>   separately?.

The OS doesn't *have* to understand an encoding.  You're perfectly free to use a third-party encoding library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) or [GNU libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to convert between your encoding and the OS's native encoding, at the application level.

> 2)Will a font always have the complete implementation of a code page or just part of it?.

In the days of 7-bit (128-character) and 8-bit (256-character) encodings, it was common for fonts to include glyphs for the entire code page.  It is *not* common today for fonts to include all 100,000+ assigned characters in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide you with short answers to your questions.

1. It's generally not the OS that supports an encoding but the applications. Encodings are used to convert a stream of bytes to lists of characters. For example, in C# reading a UTF-8 string will automatically make it UTF-16 if you tell it to treat it as a string.
   No matter what encoding you use, C# will simply use UTF-16 internally and when you want to, for example, print a string from a *foreign* encoding, it will convert it to UTF-16 first, then look up the corresponding characters in the character tables (fonts) and shows the glyphs.
2. I don't recall ever seeing a complete font. I don't have much experience with working with fonts either, so I cannot give you an answer for this one.
3. The answer to this one is in #1, but a short summary: fonts are usually encoding-independent, meaning that as long as the system can convert the input encoding to the font encoding you'll be fine.

Bonus answer: On "*how does the OS understand network protocols it doesn't know?*": again it's not the OS that handles them but the application. As long as the OS knows where to redirect the traffic (which application) it really doesn't need to care about the protocol. Low-level protocols usually do have to be installed, to allow the OS to know where to send the data.

*This answer is based on my understanding of encodings, which may be wrong. Do correct me if that's the case!*

Comment: It is not the application that supports character encoding but some SDK. Is it part of OS? Depends. Win32 definitely is integral part of Windows. And some services like Input Methods, GDI+, font-caching, etc. are also part of the Windows OS. In contrast, on Linux these kind of services are usually part of X Windows or Windows Manager, although some libraries are also standalone (take [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) as an example). It's complicated ;)